# Replacing 20A MWBC breakers with 15A

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I recently moved into a house and had a home inspection, where the inspector noted that the motor powering a jet hot tub in the basement must be on a GFCI (it was not). When trying to figure out which breaker it was on so I could work on replacing it, I discovered that all of the basement wiring was done with 14 gauge but was protected with 20 amp breakers. They also used a 20 amp receptacle in the bathroom for some reason.

Here's a diagram of what I've found so far:

[image: basement wiring diagram]

And a photo of the breakers in the panel (two left-most):
[image: basement 20 amp breakers]

So it appears to be a multi-wire branch circuit, with one hot powering the tub and the other hot heading into a junction box where it splits off to everything else in the basement (bathroom GFCI, bathroom light, basement wall plugs, basement closet light).

My questions are:

1. I assume that at a minimum, I need to do the following. Is this correct?:

   1. Replace the 20 amp breakers with a two-pole 15 amp breaker ([like this](https://www.canadabreakers.ca/collections/cutler-hammer-breakers/products/br215))
   2. Replace the non-GFCI receptacle powering powering the hot tub with a GFCI (hot and neutral go into the `LINE` half)
   3. Replace the 20 amp GFCI receptacle in the bathroom with a 15 amp GFCI (hot and neutral go into the `LINE` half)
2. Would an AFCI breaker ([like this](https://www.canadabreakers.ca/collections/cutler-hammer-breakers/products/brl215caf)) be allowed here instead?
3. Do I need to decipher the mess inside the junction box on the right side of the diagram before proceeding?
4. From what I've gathered, a shared neutral is only allowed if the two hots are on opposite phases. Is it sufficient to measure 240V between the two hots?

My jurisdiction is Ontario, Canada.

Comment: You could use a 15A two-pole GFCI breaker, whcih would GFCI-protect both sides. Depending how closely CEC pairs to NEC, you might need to run a 20A line to the bathroom receptacle (so no need to replace that GFCI, just a need to power it with 20A on 12Ga.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I was about to write up an answer "Yes, you've got it all correct, but GFCI breaker would make sense due to MWBC and multiple GFCI receptacles, etc." You commented first - write it up and I'll +1.

Comment: Write it up. I have no particular need for more "points" and  was not fully fleshing out an answer here.

Comment: Yes, measuring 240V across both hots, phase to phase, will allow you to share the neutral.  Don't need to decipher the junction box... we got it.

Comment: You are correct on the handle tied 15 amp breaker since it is a mwbc. Also since it is a 15 amp circuit you can’t have the 20 amp receptacle You really do not want an AFCI in this circuit it will have problems with a motor load and being on a mwbc. The shared hots are actually on the same phase but that phase is split and each leg is 180 out. 3 phase is each phase is 120 degrees out of phase.

Comment: Thanks! Would the two-pole GFCI breaker "know" that the neutral is shared, so that A current minus B current = neutral current? I assume that's why there's a third terminal on the breaker -- neutral from the 14/3 goes into the third terminal, and the coiled neutral attached to the breaker goes into the panel's neutral bus bar, right?